# Event Campaigns and Grand Prize

Tags: star-trek-online

I have a question about how event campaigns work in Star Trek: Online. I'm a free-to-play player and want to get a free tier 6 ship by engaging in the campaign.

The STO Wiki says that "50 Event Campaign Progress is earned for each "Daily" run of any Eligible Event, with a cooldown of 20 hours between acquiring more. A total of 3,500 Event Campaign Progress is needed to earn this Event Grand Prize." Is this true? If I get 50 event progress per event, I'd have to complete any of the featured events 70 times, and unfortunately, I don't have nearly enough time on my hands for that. So do I have to repeat the events enough to get 3500 event progress and earn the grand prize?

Comment: Your [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396110/how-do-event-campaigns-work) would have likely been reopened. Please, don't delete closed questions to ask them again.

Comment: Somehow, I doubt that. If my previous *two* questions were closed so quickly, I wouldn't be surprised if people found a new reason to keep the question closed.

Comment: Is there a reason this was downvoted? Or was it just "too broad" again?

Comment: @SovereignInquiry I downvoted - not because it was broad - but because, as pinckerman stated, deleting and re-posting questions to get around closures goes against the nature of the system. Your previous question had 3 re-opened votes, so it would have only been a matter of time because it was reopened

Comment: @Wondercricket If the asker deleted their question and asked another one that meets our criteria, I think it's fine. It's true that we don't want people re-asking questions to get around rules. But we are completely fine with people reasking questions if the new question complies with our standards, especially if they delete their old one. They're actively trying to make the content in this community better. We should celebrate that.

Taken in isolation, I think this question would be accepted. So I don't think it's worth downvoting. But maybe this is a conversation best had in Meta. :)

Comment: @Shaun "we are completely fine with people reasking questions [..] if they delete their old one", since when?

Comment: @pinckerman I say this because I'm unaware that we explicitly guide people away from it in our guidelines for deletion. We basically say "you can delete your own question if it has no answers and it doesn't add anything to the site".

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions

If you can point me to the rule that says people aren't allowed to delete their own unanswered question in favor of asking a better version of that question, I'll consider this a learning moment. :)

Comment: @Shaun the previous question was tecnically closed for a reason, it looks wrong to me deleting and re-asking it. Also because there was a reopen vote on-going. As Wondercricket pointed out, getting around closures goes against the nature of the system. And it's not true that the old quesiton didn't add anything to the site, since you were "happy to answer it once it re-opens."

Comment: @Shaun I couldn't find anywhere that explicitly states this, but it is a running issue that *highly* discouraged through most sites. Some relevant meta posts I did find are: [How long should I wait before deleting a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138686/how-long-should-i-wait-before-deleting-a-closed-question) and [How can we stop premature deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171763/how-can-we-stop-premature-deletion/171772)

Answer (score 2):

An *event campaign* takes place over 5 *events*. For each *event*, you're provided a series of *activities*. Each day, if you want to progress through the event, you must perform 1-2 *activities* that day. Once you do, you get 1) progress toward the *event* reward, and 2) 50 points toward the *event campaign* reward. Once you get 3500 points toward the *event campaign*, you get the *event campaign* reward.

You aren't expected to get all 3,500 points in a single *event*. It's actually impossible to do so. Most events last ~21 days (or 105 days for 5 events). If you engaged once a day, you could only get 1,050 points toward the *event campaign* in a single event. At a minimum, you'd need to complete every day in 3 events and part of a 4th to get 3,500 points. That said, you also don't have to do it that way. As long as you get credit for ~2/3 of the days within *events* that are part of the *event campaign*, you'll have enough by the end of the last event to get the reward.

Some caveats to be aware of:

- You can't get more than 50 points per day toward the *event campaign*. You're forced to perform *activities* across 70 different days.
- Not every *event* grants progress toward the *event campaign*. Read the *event* description to see if it will, or check the *event campaign* interface to see if the active event is listed as one of the 5 *events* within the campaign.
- When you finish your progress toward the prize for a single *event*, you can continue to repeat it for extra dilithium rewards. As you collect each reward, you'll get an additional 50 points toward the *event campaign*.
- Depending on the *event*, you have to get 1 or 2 "daily progress points" before you get credit for the day (and thus your 50 points). For *events* where you need 2 daily progress points per day, there are usually some quicker *activities* worth 1 point, and more time-intensive ones worth 2. So, it's still possible to get your daily credit through one *activity*. However, depending on which *activities* you choose, you may need to do 2 in a day to get full credit.
- For the purposes of this answer, I referred to "days", which is what the experience ends up being for most players. However, the timers are actually "20-hour" timers. So, if you do the activities as soon as the timer expires, you can earn an extra 50 points.